# Why is a ten point font smaller in Debian compared to Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, fonts, fontconfig

I use Debian 7.7.0 and my `~/.Xresources` file contains

```
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.autohint: false
Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
Xft.rgba: rgb
```

(These are the settings I used in Ubuntu 14.04 to maintain the same font rendering when using a simple window manager started from the console.)

The system font is set to DejaVu Sans at ten points and the word "File" is rendered like this:

[image: Font rendering in Debian]

With the same settings in Ubuntu 14.04 each letter is one pixel higher:

[image: Font rendering in Ubuntu]

Since each letter has the same width in both cases the rendering in Debian looks vertically squashed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those settings don't do anything because they only apply to the old X11 font server, which nobody uses anymore.  Also applications don't request a font size of 10 pixels... they request 10 ( or whatever ) *point*, which is 10/72nds of an inch.  That size gets translated to a number of pixels based on the dpi of the screen.

Comment: @psusi The settings surely affect the font rendering and supports more applications than `fontconfig` do, at least in my case where I start a window manager from the console. Thanks for teaching be about the units, I thought the requested unit was pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `Xft.dpi` from 96 to 100 solved the problem for me. Now the letters have the same shape as in Ubuntu.