# How do I make all GTK applications use a custom DPI setting?

Tags: x11, gtk, dpi

After upgrading from Debian 8 to Debian 9, the text editor Pluma (a Gedit fork) no longer use my custom DPI setting. I noticed the same thing with the editor Geany. Here are my Xft settings in `~/.Xresources`:

```
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.autohint: false
Xft.dpi: 100
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
Xft.rgba: rgb
```

The other Xft settings above are picked up Pluma, however. On the other hand, the text editor Leafpad correctly uses the DPI setting. Any clues? I use the window manager Blackbox started from a console.

Pluma (with DejaVu Sans 10):

[image]

Leafpad (with DejaVu Sans 10):

[image]

Comment: Why is your question GTK specific? Looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me... Do you have the same issue with Qt based applications?

Comment: I don't use any Qt based applications, so making it work for GTK applications is at least a starting point. Here is the X problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165250/why-is-a-ten-point-font-smaller-in-debian-compared-to-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

GTK3 use [theming](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html), so you need to configure the style sheets used by it (not `~/.Xresources`). Read also about [GTK application](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html) resources.

The `gnome-tweak-tool` application and package provides a GUI interface to changing themes, etc.

You might consider setting the `scale` property of fonts. It is not exactly the DPI, but is related (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44474008/841108)).

<sup>(perhaps the GTK theming machinery knows about DPI, but I can't tell how)</sup>

BTW, if using Xorg X11 server, you could consider configuring the DPI resolution of your screen (see e.g. [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Display_size_and_DPI)); read also about [xrandr](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html). this works on the server side so should has an effect on every X11 client (even non-GTK based). If using Wayland, you might find something relevant too.

Comment: What configuration file should I use? What property should I set?